# How do I repopulate form fields after validation errors with express-form?

Tags: validation, node.js, express

Using node.js and express (2.5.9) with express-form.

How should I repopulate form fields with the submitted values?

I have a `get` and a `post` route. If there are validation errors when the form is posted, I redirect the user back to the get, the problem is that the repopulated locals don't show up (I do have autoLocals: true, so I assume it's because I am redirecting and `res` is reset.)

So how do you guys repopulate and what's your application flow, do you `res.send` instead of `res.redirect` and set up the whole thing again? That seems repetitive.

Here's an example of my post route:

```
app.post(

  '/projects/:id'

  , form(field("title").required("title", "Title is required)
  , function (req, res){

  if (!req.form.isValid){
    res.redirect('/project/'+req.params.id+'/edit');
  }
  else{
    // save to db
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's best practice, but when I have validation failure, I don't redirect I just re-render the view (often by passing control to the 'get' callback).  Somethign like this:

```
function loadProject(req,res, id){ /* fetch or create logic, storing as req.model or req.project */} 

function editProject(req,res){ /* render logic */ }

function saveProject(req,res){ 
    if(!req.form.isValid){ 
        editProject(req,res);
    }else{
        saveToDb(req.project);
        res.redirect('/project'+req.project.id+'/edit');
    }
}

app.param('id', loadProject);
app.get('/projects/:id/edit', editProject);
app.post('/projects/:id', saveProject);
```

Comment: Ok, cool. So my problem was the fact that I was doing a redirect and res got reset. What I learned though, is that there's a separate problem when trying to repopulate fields that have "multi-level" names/paths like `project[title]` (as is typically the case when using mongoose). They don't repopulate. Going to have to dig into express-form some more and see if it's something that can be worked around.

Answer (score 7):

I am working with expressjs4.0 to repopulate the forms fields after validation you do:

```
router.route('/posts/new')
 .get(function(req, res) {
 res.render('posts/new', new Post({}));
});
```

The second argument in res.render below will set some variables in the view.

```
res.render('posts/new', new Post({}));
```

In my view I then set my form fields as follows:

```
...
<input type="text" name="title" value="<%- post.title %>">
<textarea name="article"><%- post.article %></textarea>
...
```

When you submit this form, it should be caught by your router like so:

```
router.route('/posts')
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var post = new Post(req.body)
      post.save(function(err) {
       if (err) {
         res.locals.errors = err.errors;
         res.locals.post = post;
         return res.render('posts/new');
       }
      return res.redirect('/posts');
  });
  ...
})
```

This line of code, resets the form fields in your view

```
res.locals.post = post;
```

I hope someone finds this useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had to work on similar problem recently and used two node modules: validator and flashify.

In the form view I configured my form fields as follows:

```
div.control-group
        label.control-label Description
        div.controls
          textarea(name='eventForm[desc]', id='desc', rows='3').input-xxlarge= eventForm.desc

      div.control-group
        label.control-label Tag
        div.controls
          select(id='tag', name='eventForm[tag]')
            tags = ['Medjugorje', 'Kibeho', 'Lourdes', 'Fatima']
            for tag in tags
              option(selected=eventForm.tag == tag)= tag
```

Notice the naming convention of the form fields.  Then in my config file I set one global variable, which is really just a placeholder for when the form first loads:

```
//locals
app.locals.eventForm = []; // placeholder for event form repopulation
```

The validation logic is in my router file and looks like this:

```
 app.post('/posts', function(req, res){
    var formData = req.body.eventForm;
    var Post = models.events;
    var post = new Post();

    post.text          = formData.desc;
    post.tag           = formData.tag;

    // run validations before saving
    var v = new Validator();
    var isPostValid = true;

    // custom error catcher for validator, which uses flashify
    v.error = function(msg) {
     res.flash('error', msg);
     isPostValid = false;
    }

    v.check(post.text, "Description field cannot be empty").notEmpty();
    v.check(post.tag, "Tag field cannot be empty").notEmpty();
```

Then I check to see there are errors, and if so, pass the form data back to the view:

```
  // reject it
  res.render('Event.jade', {page: req.session.page, eventForm: formData});
```

Notice this evenForm data gets passed back to the view, which repopulates the default values.

The final step is to include the flashify component in your form view.

```
div(style='margin-top: 60px').container-fluid
      include flashify
```

The code for the flashify view looks like this:

```
if (flash.error != undefined)
div.container
    div.alert.alert-error
        b Oops!
        button(type='button', data-dismiss='alert').close &times;
        ul
            each error in flash.error
                li= error
if (flash.success != undefined)
div.container
    div.alert.alert-success
        b Success!
        button(type='button', data-dismiss='alert').close &times;
        ul
            each success in flash.success
                li= success
```